# Creating/Resolving a list of objects using Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm learning IoC and Autofac so my question is rather basic but I couldn't find satisfactory answer. I have these test classes:

DataModel.cs

```
public class DataModel : IDataModel
{
    public int PosX { get; set; }
    public int PosY { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DataModel(int posx, int posy, string name)
    {
        PosX = posx;
        PosY = posy;
        Name = name;
    }
    public void WriteName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello, my name is \"{Name}\". Nice to meet you!");
    }
    public void WritePosition()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\"{Name}\": Position of X axis is {PosX} and position of Y axis is {PosY}");
    }

}
```

BusinessLogic.cs

```
public class BusinessLogic : IBusinessLogic
{
    ILogger _logger;
    IList<IDataModel> _dataModels;
    public BusinessLogic(ILogger logger, IList<IDataModel> dataModels)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _dataModels = dataModels;
    }

    

    public void ProcessData()
    {

        
        _logger.Log("Starting the processing of devices data.");
        _logger.Log("Processing the data...");
        foreach (var model in _dataModels)
        {
            model.WriteName();
            model.WritePosition();
        }
        
        _logger.Log("Finished processing the data.");
    }
}
```

Now as you can see ctor of BusinessLogic needs collection of IDataModel. The question is how do I create List of Interfaces stored in the container to achieve something like this:

```
for(int x = 0; x <=7; x++)
{
  for(int y = 0; y <= 7; y++)
  {
    list.Add(new DataModel(x,y,$"Object {x}{y}"));
  }
}
```

Maybe I got the whole idea wrong. I am grateful for every answer. Thanks!

Comment: You wouldn't normally register 'data' classes in the container. You'd normally register some other service like a repository that can deliver the data objects. You _can_ register multiple objects using `RegisterInstance` or as a `Func` for creating one when needed, but these would also normally be services, like say two `WeatherService` instances for different locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `IList<IDataModel> dataModels` is not a service, to be resolved. I'm not sure that it is the best way, however you have to create a service (for example `IDataInitializer`) providing a method or an object for `IList<IDataModel> dataModels`, register it on `IServiceCollection` or `IOC` container in `Startup.cs` and then it can be resolved in other services and classes.

Here is an example:

```
public interface IDataInitializer
{
    IList<IDataModel> GetDataModel();
}
public class DataInitializer : IDataInitializer
{
    private IList<IDataModel> _dataModels;
    public DataInitializer()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x <= 7; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y <= 7; y++)
            {
                _dataModels.Add(new DataModel(x, y, $"Object {x}{y}"));
            }
        }
    }
    public IList<IDataModel> GetDataModel()
    {
        return _dataModels;
    }

}

public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IDataInitializer>(new DataModel());
}
```

Comment: Thank You! You cleared a few things to me. Now i remeber seeing similar problem in FAQ section of Autofac documentation. I just interpreted it wrong. Thanks !